# HTACCES index.php Parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a problem with my .htaccess file.

**My Problem**

When i enter my webpage with the following url:

```
http://www.website.com/sys/module/photos/
```

I can add on that page some photo's by the following url:

```
http://www.website.com/sys/module/photos/add/10/
```

or

```
http://www.website.com/sys/module/photos/add/485/
```

Now i have pagination on the index.php file and i want to enter the page like this:

```
http://www.website.com/sys/module/photos/
```

And go to the next page with the following url:

```
http://www.website.com/sys/module/photos/1/
```

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule add/(.*)/$ add.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

But if I go now to `http://www.website.com/sys/module/photos/add/10/` it wil display the content of index.php file.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: I think it's because of the rule `RewriteRule (.*)/$ index.php?page=$1`.

 `.*` will basically match `http://www.website.com/sys/module/photos/add/10/` completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your htaccess file is in the "photos" folder, so then you're rules need to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^add/([0-9]+)/?$ add.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You'll be narrowing down what you match be limiting the capture groups to only numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule add/(.*)/$ add.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^$ index.php
```

As mentioned in the comments, the `.*` will match everything, including the url `http://www.website.com/sys/module/photos/add/10/`.

The solution is to change the bottom rewrite rule to only match the homepage (when your path is /)

Comment: Your second rule uses a backreference but there's no capture group

Comment: Ah yes, I have since removed the backreference